# Lost my root access and unable to install any software or any other priviliged operations

Tags: sudo, root

I have been using Precise Pangolin and I am into a problem now :( I was trying to add my current user to the group vboxusers.. So I used the command,

```
sudo usermod -G vboxusers myusername
```

And it got succeded too. But after adding like that, I am unable to perform any sudo operations. Whenever i use a sudo command I get an error message stating "myusername is not in sudoers file".

I tried enabling root account also. But I couldn't. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As enzotib comments, a good way is to restart in [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and write

```
for i in adm cdrom sudo video plugdev lpadmin; do adduser myusername $i; done
```

Substituting `myusername` as required. This will add you to all the important groups, including **sudo**, which gives you access to sudo.

Comment: A less complex command is `sudo usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,sudo,video,plugdev,lpadmin myusername`.

Comment: Thank You guys. :) I have not tried the above mentioned solution. Will let u know whether it worked or not, once after i try :)

Comment: Thankyou guys. It is working :) :) Linux rocks and Linux users Rock to the core :)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately that command do the wrong thing, because gives you only that group and removes all others. `usermod` should be avoided, there are better and simpler tools to use.

The solution is to start in recovery mode and add your user to the `sudo` group.

To add a user to a group, I usually use

```
sudo gpasswd -a $user $group
```

many others prefer to use

```
sudo adduser $user $group
```

Both these commands do not change the set of groups to which the user already belongs.

Comment: mentioning which those better and simpler tools are would be helpful.