# User stopped being sudoer after release upgrade

Tags: server, upgrade, sudo, do-release-upgrade, passwd

I've upgraded one of web server, that was running Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 (No downtime since it's creation, though serving 10-40k requests/daily).

```
 sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
 do-release-upgrade
```

During upgrade everything seemed normal. Restarted the instance (EC2): apache2, mysql - all seem to be running. But:

```
g****c@ip-10-**-**-***:~$ sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
[sudo] password for g****c:
g****c is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

(I've backed up the instance before upgrading: On origin this user is sudoer).
How can I solve this issue ? 
How do I do regain su on remote server?

Answer (score 0):

You are in for some troubles. Unless you have a root user password set or access to another user still having sudo capabilities, you are out of luck and will have to get the machine into recovery mode somehow.

This may require physical access, but if you are using a hosted server, your hosting provider usually offers a web interface that may get your machine into that mode. Back up everything NOW if you haven't done so already.

If you can manage to get your machine into recovery mode, follow this post to regain sudo capabilities:

[Lost my root access and unable to install any software or any other priviliged operations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169631/lost-my-root-access-and-unable-to-install-any-software-or-any-other-priviliged-o)

Comment: AWS dashboard doesn't seem to have such option (Yes, back-ups are daily/weekly and scheduled with cron)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/170858/how-to-boot-ec2-instance-into-safe-mode

Comment: If you use EBS you are lucky, if not, all you can do is to do a reinstall and revert your system to your last backup (as far as I know). But I am by no means experienced in recovering AWS instances, all systems I worked on were dedicated machines...